# add 10 pixels from bottom after text inside parent div with class vAlign?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to make my text inside div with same margin from bottom as margin from top (now it is set on 10px)? Thank you very much. PS: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b4dh2/)

CSS:

```
.content_txt .h3 a{
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
.content_txt .h3{
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-body content_txt" style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 253); height: auto;">
  <div class="vAlign">
   <h3 class="h3" style="color:#236EE8;margin:0;padding:0;">
     <a class="ui-link" href="/cz/cs/65_chystane-akce/2155_automan-expo.html?do=article" style="color:#236EE8;"> 30th Annual CMSC Confere </a>
   </h3>
   <b>21.7.2014 | North Charleston, SC (US)  (SG)</b>
   <br class="clear">
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.content_txt').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('.vAlign').height() > 30){
                    $(this).css('height','auto');           
            }else{
                $(this).css('height','60px');
            }
});
```

HTML:

Comment: It would be more appropriate to put the `h3` inside the `a` tag.

Comment: Thank you for advice but can I modify current code with `a` inside `h3` to have `margin 10px` on bottom where text ends ?

Comment: like `margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px !important;` ?

Comment: @Batu Zet as U can see not all text is inside `h3` tag U can see `b` tag below for example. All is wrapped in `div` with class `vAlign`.

Comment: I think `style =""` needs to be removed in the `h3` tag, because it might overrule the CSS rule. Then CSS margin: `margin: (top) (right) (bottom) (left)` Or `margin: (top & bottom) (left & right)` Which means you can do this for 10px margin: `margin: 10px 0`

Comment: Please CHECK my Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4dh2/ to understand my problem I need to add 10px to bottom where text ends i mean all text in parent div with class vAlign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got a working solution for you by adding some padding to content_txt. The following code is my modified version of the css in your fiddle.

```
.content_txt .h3 a{
font-weight: normal !important;
}
.content_txt {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are asking wrong qustion as for inside text you will need padding not margin.. as by reading your lines may b you want this..

```
.content_txt .h3{
    border:1px solid;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
    padding-bottom:20px !important;
}
```

or else plz tell us more clearyly that what you want...sorry if i understood you wrong

or may be you want this..

```
.content_txt .h3{
    margin: 10px !important;

}
```

sry i cant ask you by comment as m not able to write comment so if i understood you wrong then sorry..